# I cannot install tor-browser on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, tor-browser

I downloaded tor-browser from official website (https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/6.5.1/tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz).

Following instructions on the official website, I entered a command but I cannot install it.

```
$ tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-6.5.1_en-US.tar.xz
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

---

I do not want to install by adding the webupd8 PPA.

Please follow the official website and tell me how to install.